# VBA to create groups in Excel and then sort each group

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list in excel of parts and when the were purchased.  The parts are listed in 4 rows.  The first row is a summary of all on-hand.  The next three rows represent how many are on-hand at each purchased price.  I have over 200 parts and I know how to manually group them, but am interested in writing the VBA code that will create a group for each change in Part No.  Then once grouped, within that group, I want to have the bottom 3 rows sorted from oldest to newest and if there are any blanks leaving them on the bottom of the group.

```
Part No.    Part Description    On-Hand  Price      Date      Ordered   Bol #   
55 NIT            NC               21                   
55 NIT            NC               10    15.00      09/18/13    15  115352-00
55 NIT            NC               6     15.10      10/09/13    6   135216-00
55 NIT            NC               5     15.05      11/17/13    5   156849-00  
404 R             cooling          2                    
404 R             cooling          1     112.00     08/29/13    2   147859-00
404 R             cooling          1     102.82     09/18/13    1   159568-00
404 R             cooling          0     102.82
```

@ARich  This is what I have for the grouping.  I don't think it is the most efficient way of doing it, but it gets the job done for a known number of parts.  I am not sure how to code it to pick up all the data and run the loop until it has covered all rows.

```
Sub Makegroups4()

'   create a group out of every 4 rows.  Skip the first row so it still shows and group the other three rows.
'
'   i will be used to identify 1st row in group

    i = 5

    For x = 1 To 175

        Rows(i & ":" & (i + 2)).Select
        Selection.Rows.Group

        i = i + 4

    Next



End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried? Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. [See This.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a PivotTable, with `Part No.` above `Date` in Row Labels and Average of `Price` for Σ Values.

Comment: I can't use an average price.  This is going to be used for accounting and the numbers have to be the actual FIFO value.  I will play with the pivot table though and see if I can figure out a way to make that work.  Thank you for the idea. @pnuts